# Reactive Java Mono.zip with Mono.empty() parameters

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

Using Spring with Reactor Project to zip multiple api calls as aggregated result.
Can Mono.zip() with Mono.empty() parameters return null result?

```java
Mono<Dog> dogMono = dogApiClient.getDog(); // can return Mono.empty()
Mono<Cat> catMono = catMono = catApiClient.getCat(); // can returnMono.empty()
Mono<Horse> horseMono = horseApiClient.getHorse(); // can return Mono.empty()

Mono.zip(dogMono, dogMobo, horseMono)
  .map(this::mapToAnimals);
```

Expected result:

```json
{
  dog: null, // if dog is null
  cat: null, // if cat is null
  horse: null, // if horse is null
}
```

Actual result:

```json
{
  dog: {
    name: null,
    surname: null
  }, 
  cat: {
    name: null,
    surname: null
  }, 
  horse: {
    name: null,
    surname: null
  }
}
```

or

```json
"" // empty
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's certainly not an elegant solution, but you can choose to wrap your values inside Optional:

```java
Mono<Optional<Dog>> dogMono = Mono.just(Optional.empty());
if(condition1) {
    dogMono = dogApiClient.getDog().map(Optional::of);
}

Mono<Optional<Cat>> catMono = Mono.just(Optional.empty());
if(condition2) {
    catMono = catApiClient.getCat().map(Optional::of);
}

Mono<Optional<Horse>> horseMono = Mono.just(Optional.empty());
if(condition3) {
    horseMono = horseApiClient.getHorse().map(Optional::of);
}

Mono.zip(dogMono, catMono, horseMono)
    .map(this::mapToAnimals);

private Output mapToAnimals(Tuple3<Optional<Dog>, Optional<Cat>, Optional<Horse>> tuple3)
{
    Dog dog = tuple3.getT1().orElse(null);
    Cat cat = tuple3.getT2().orElse(null);
    Horse horse = tuple3.getT3().orElse(null);

    return new Output(dog, cat, horse);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Reactive Streams, the `null` value is forbidden. Furthermore, `zip` expect that all combined publishers have the same number of elements. Or to put it differently: it short-circuits as soon as one of the publishers completes.

So if you use `Mono.empty()`, that `Mono` completes immediately and triggers the `zip` to complete empty as well.

One possible solution would be to have a "null object" instance of each animal, like this:

```
public static final Dog NO_DOG = new Dog(...);
public static final Cat NO_CAT = new Cat(...);
public static final Horse NO_HORSE = new Horse(...);

Mono<Dog> dogMono = (condition1) ? Mono.just(dogApliClient.getDog()) : Mono.just(NO_DOG);
Mono<Cat> catMono = (condition2) ? Mono.just(catApliClient.getCat()) : Mono.just(NO_CAT);
Mono<Horse> horseMono = (condition3) ? Mono.just(horseApliClient.getHorse()) : Mono.just(NO_HORSE);

Mono.zip(dogMono, catMono, horseMono)
    .map(Animals::fromDogCatAndHorse);

Map<String, Object> fromDogCatAndHorse(Tuple3<Dog, Cat, Horse> tuple) {
    Map<String, Object> forJson = new HashMap<>(3);

    Dog dog = tuple.getT1();
    if (dog = NO_DOG) json.put("dog", null); else json.put("dog", dog);

    Cat cat = tuple.getT2();
    if (cat = NO_CAT) json.put("cat", null); else json.put("cat", cat);

    Horse horse = tuple.getT3();
    if (horse = NO_HORSE) json.put("horse", null); else json.put("horse", horse);

    return forJson;
}
```

If you can't define these null object instances, then the solution from @yossarian would work too.

**Note that there's still a big issue with the api client calls, though**: the `Mono.just(apiClient.blockingCall())` pattern.

Here you're essentially shoehorning a blocking call inside what is supposed to be a non-blocking controller...

Ideally these clients would return a `Mono<Dog|Cat|Horse>` to reflect a non-blocking nature.
As an example, with a proper non-blocking API, `dogMono` can be initialized like this:

```
Mono<Dog> dogMono = (condition1) ? dogApiClient.getDogAsync() : Mono.just(NO_DOG);
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution