# Mono.zip with null

Tags: mono, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

My code:

```
Mono.zip(
            credentialService.getCredentials(connect.getACredentialsId()),
            credentialService.getCredentials(connect.getBCredentialsId())
)
.flatMap(...
```

From the frontend we get `connect` object with 2 fields:

```
connect{
aCredentialsId : UUID //required
bCredentialsId : UUID //optional
}
```

So sometimes the second line `credentialService.getCredentials(connect.getBCredentialsId()))` can return `Mono.empty`

How to write code to be prepared for this empty Mono when my second field `bCredentialsId` is null?

What should I do? In case of empty values `return Mono.just(new Object)` and then check if `obj.getValue != null`??? I need to fetch data from DB for 2 different values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Reactor: Mono.zip from multi api sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57363224/spring-reactor-mono-zip-from-multi-api-sources)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The strategy I prefer here is to declare an `optional()` utility method like so:

```
public class Utils {

    public static <T> Mono<Optional<T>> optional(Mono<T> in) {
        return in.map(Optional::of).switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(Optional.empty()));
    }

}
```

...which then allows you to transform your second `Mono` to one that will always return an optional, and thus do something like:

```
Mono.zip(
        credentialService.getCredentials(connect.getACredentialsId()),
        credentialService.getCredentials(connect.getBCredentialsId()).transform(Utils::optional)
).map(e -> new Connect(e.getT1(), e.getT2()))
```

(...assuming you have a `Connect` object that takes an `Optional` as the second parameter of course.)

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is using mono's `defaultIfEmpty` method.

```
Mono<String> m1 = credentialService.getCredentials(connect.getACredentialsId());
Mono<String> m2 = credentialService.getCredentials(connect.getBCredentialsId()).defaultIfEmpty("");

Mono.zip(m1, m2).map(t -> connectService.connect(t.getT1(), t.getT2()));
```

Explanation: if m2 is null then get empty string as a default value instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using .zip here, I would work with a nullable property of Connect and use .flatMap in combination with .switchIfEmpty for it.

Kotlin-Version:

```
val aCredentials = credentialService.getCredentials(connect.getACredentialsId())

credentialService.getCredentials(connect.getBCredentialsId())
       .flatMap { bCredentials -> aCredentials
                      .map { Connect(it, bCredentials)}
                      .switchIfEmpty(Connect(null, bCredentials)) 
        }
       .switchIfEmpty { aCredentials.map { Connect(it, null) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the problem
When the mono is empty, the zipWith does not work and I used the "switchIfEmpty"

```
emptyMono
            .zipWith(otherMono)
            .map(tuple -> do(tuple.getT2(), tuple.getT1()))
            .switchIfEmpty(otheMonor.map(x->do(x)));
```